# Are there any action like 'init_frontend'

Tags: admin, hooks, front-end, init

I've found init and init_admin. Are there any action that executes just in the frontend?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can combine `add_action()` and an `is_admin()` check:

```
! is_admin() and add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_callback' );
```

Now the callback function will run on front-end only.

Answer (score 5):

'template_redirect' is the most useful one.

Comment: In some situations this may actually be a better solution. Just because `is_admin()` is false doesn't mean we are on the frontend. For example, if you trigger `wp-cron.php` from the CLI, `is_admin()` is false but the frontend is not rendered. Rather than checking for `is_admin()`, `is_ajax()`, `is_feed()`, etc. it's simpler to hook into `template_redirect` which guarantees we are on the frontend.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but found the other answers not quite as clear.

There is no `init`-like hook that is front-end only.

`admin_init` **only** runs in the dashboard.

`init` runs on **both** the front-end **as well as** the dashboard.

So, combining the built-in WordPress function [is_admin()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin), and the `init` hook, you can construct a function that allows you to do front-end only things:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_init_frontend_only_function' );

function my_init_frontend_only_function() {
    // exit function if not on front-end
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // remaining code will only run on the front end....
    // do stuff here....
}
```

Comment: I changed your code (I assumed you meant `if ( is_admin() ) { return; }`, not `! is_admin()` ). If I assumed wrong, feel free to revert it.

Comment: Prefer this answer (and the edit); it's clear what it intends to do. Most novice PHP have no clue what `and` does and what logical operators do without any assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_loaded` action for this.

```
// If u want to load a function only in the front end.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_front_end_function');
function my_front_end_function() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) { 
        // Only target the front end
        // Do what you need to do
    }
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded

Comment: You can use that `! is_admin()` trick on pretty much any action hook; it's not specific to `wp_loaded`.

Comment: Correct, but it can be useful to admin to see that comment so it's to target frontend nonadmin. Does that sound about right?